How to create a node based on the NID of a deleted node?
In the past I have deleted /node/1 but I want to create content in it again instead redirecting from it.
How could I do this in Drupal 10.3.1?

Programmatically: When creating the node, simply pass the nid:
Node::create([
  …other fields…
  'nid' => 1,
])->save();

UI: Install the Custom Nid module, which

allows site builders to create node with their custom nid. If the node with given nid is already exist a message will occur that "Nid already exists".

